# Vue 2 - getting computed backgroundImage dynamically

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have few divs and I need to set the backgrounds of each from values that I have in an array. I have tried to set the background overlay to each of them by creating the computed property:

```
 computed: {
      backgroundImage(url) {
        let overlay = 'linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))';
        return 'background-image:'+ overlay +' , url(' + url + ');';
      }
    }
```

And then I was thinking of passing the url like this to computed property:

```
:style="{ backgroundImage: url(`${articles[0].image.src}`) }"
```

But, that doesn't work, I am not getting the computed value back, how can I do that?

Comment: This might not solve your problem but you should not return the `background-image` since you already have that part defined in your style binding. Perhaps you can show use what actually comes out of the style binding.

Comment: I just get the ```style="background: url("http://my.app/content/uploads/2017/08/5948f40c8b13a84b075de6e9.png");"```, without the overlay.

Comment: Why are you hardcoding the `overlay` CSS in your computed property by the way? Why not use both `background-image` and `background-color` instead of the composite `background`? This way you can easily solve it with CSS.

Answer (score 2):

For computed property :

```
computed: {
    backgroundImage: () => (url) => {
        let overlay = 'linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))';
        return 'url("' + url + '"), ' + overlay;
    }
}
```

and for methods:

```
methods: {
    backgroundImage(url) {
        let overlay = 'linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))';
        return 'url("' + url + '"), ' + overlay;
    }
}
```

usage :

```
:style="{ 'background-image': backgroundImage(articles[0].image.src)}"
```

Comment: @Leff I've updated my answer. you are using `rgba(0, 0, 0, .5)` for both gradient colors and this will return a simple flat color not gradient.

Answer (score -1):

if your data is fixed and the background won't change, then you could simply set the background like:

```
:style="{ background: `url(${articles[0].image.src})`}"
```

if the `articles` have to be computed first, then you could put that, or some other values in your computed object

```
 computed: {
   backgroundImages() { 
     const overlay = 'linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))';
     return articles.map(article => 'background-image:'+ overlay +' , url(' + articles[0].image.src + ')');
   }
```

and then:

```
:style="{ background: backgroundImages[0]}"
```

Comment: But, then I won't get the overlay which I want to set for each article

Comment: ok. i see. you could also do something like:
    backgroundImages() {
      const overlay = 'linear-gradient(270deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, .5), rgba(0, 0, 0, .5))';
      return articles.map(article => 'background-image:'+ overlay +' , url(' + articles[0].image.src + ');')
    }

and then: :style="{ background: backgroundImages[0]}"

maybe this helps.

Comment: But, I want to be able to pass many background images from the articles array, this way I will only have the background image from the first element of the array

Comment: you could add that style with different indexes for each of your divs. but i think you mean you have a (maybe long) array of articles and for each you generate a div, and want to automatically iterate through your imgs for them?
may i ask how your data / ui should look like?